# Replace 2003(!) domain controller with 2019

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2003, windows-domain, windows-server, windows-server-2019

Situation:

- Small business Windows AD Domain, 2 Controllers

  1. DC, Windows Server 2003 SP2
  2. DC, Windows Server 2008 R2
- Domain Level 2003, both function & forest

I'm tasked to add a Server 2019 DC and decommission the 2003 DC.

How would I go about raising the domainlevel as the min domainlevel for Server 2019 is 2008?

I want to avoid first removing the 2003 Server, then raising the domainlevel and then adding the 2019 Server as second DC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You need to demote the 2003 one and then you can introduce the 2019 DC having raised the functional level. You really want to get rid of the 2003 box as soon as possible. (I know that may be a pain and not within the scope of what you have been tasked with but its no longer supported.)